# Restart TEvent.WaitFor without exiting it

Tags: multithreading, wait, delphi-10-seattle

Is it possible to restart `TEvent.WaitFor` without exiting it? I need to start waiting again when `_interval` was changed by setter. For example, when one hour was set and I would like to change interval to 15 seconds, changes will come into effect when one hour is elapsed.

```
_terminatingEvent: TEvent;

procedure TTimerThread.Execute();
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do begin
    try
      _terminatingEvent.WaitFor(_interval);
      if Assigned(_onTimer) and _enabled then _onTimer(Self);
    except
      on ex: Exception do _logError(ex);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.TerminatedSet();
begin
  _terminatingEvent.SetEvent();
end;

procedure TTimerThread._setInterval(const Value: Integer);
begin
  _interval := Value;
  //Restart WaitFor here
end;
```

Currently I "solved" the issue in a following way:

```
procedure TTimerThread.Execute();
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do begin
    try
      if _terminatingEvent.WaitFor(_interval) = wrTimeout then
        if Assigned(_onTimer) and _enabled then _onTimer(Self);
    except
      on ex: Exception do _logError(ex);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.TerminatedSet();
begin
  _terminatingEvent.SetEvent();
end;

procedure TTimerThread._setInterval(const Value: Integer);
begin
  _interval := Value;
  _terminatingEvent.ResetEvent();
end;
```

It seems that when I use `SetEvent` instead of `ResetEvent`, the "set" state is saved permanently and CPU usage jumps to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `TEvent` objects, one for the timer and one for the setter, eg:

```pascal
type
  TTimerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    _terminatingEvent: TEvent;
    _updatedEvent: TEvent;
    ...
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ASuspended: Boolean); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TTimerThread.Create(ASuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(ASuspended);
  _terminatingEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
  _updatedEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
end;

destructor TTimerThread.Destroy;
begin
  _terminatingEvent.Free;
  _updatedEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.Execute;
var
  Arr: THandleObjectArray;
  SignaledObj: THandleObject;
begin
  SetLength(Arr, 2);
  Arr[0] := _terminatingEvent;
  Arr[1] := _updatedEvent;

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    try
      case THandleObject.WaitForMultiple(Arr, _interval, False, SignaledObj) of
        wrSignaled: begin
          if (SignaledObj is TEvent) then (SignaledObj as TEvent).ResetEvent();
        end;
        wrTimeOut: begin
          if Assigned(_onTimer) and _enabled then
            _onTimer(Self);
        end;
        wrError: begin
          RaiseLastOSError;
        end;
      end;
    except
      on ex: Exception do
        _logError(ex);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  _terminatingEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TTimerThread._setInterval(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if _interval <> Value then
  begin
    _interval := Value;
    _updatedEvent.SetEvent;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used a combination of `SetEvent` and `ResetEvent`. If somebody has a better answer, I will accept it.

```
procedure TTimerThread.Execute();
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do begin
    try
      case _terminatingEvent.WaitFor(_interval) of
        wrTimeout: if Assigned(_onTimer) and _enabled then _onTimer(Self);
        wrSignaled: _terminatingEvent.ResetEvent();
      end;
    except
      on ex: Exception do _logError(ex);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.TerminatedSet();
begin
  _terminatingEvent.SetEvent();
end;

procedure TTimerThread._setInterval(const Value: Integer);
begin
  _interval := Value;
  _terminatingEvent.SetEvent();
end;

procedure TTimerThread._setEnabled(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if _enabled = Value then Exit();
  _enabled := Value;
  if _enabled and Suspended then Suspended := False;
  _terminatingEvent.SetEvent();
end;
```

Comment: "*If somebody has a better answer, I will accept it*" - use two `TEvent` objects, one for the timer and the other for the setter. Wait on both events at the same time using [`THandleObject.WaitForMultiple()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.THandleObject.WaitForMultiple) and let the return value tell you which event was signaled.